# Issue saving a excel workbook in applescript

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

First post so here goes...

I am trying to write an applescript to copy a sheet from an existing workbook into a new workbook, save that new workbook with the single sheet in, then attach that workbook to an email.

I am relatively new to applescript but I have managed to get the user interaction using Cocoadialog and the script will create the new workbook then copy the sheet over but that is where the problems start.

I create the new workbook fine and then set the name of that workbook into a variable to call later.  I then copy the sheet the the var set earlier and the sheet is copied to what seems like a new workbook, so when I then save the workbook, it does save in the correct place with the correct filename but it is blank with one sheet called sheet1 in a workbook called sheet1. Enough of the explanation, here is the code...

```
set choice to 1
set tabnames to ""

repeat until (choice = 2)
     --cocoadialog dropdownbox to get target excel workbook
     set filechoice to paragraphs of (do shell script "/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog" & " fileselect --title 'This is another fileselect' --text 'Pick some files andor directories' --with-directory $HOME/Dropbox/Business/Current/")
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        open filechoice
        set sourceWorkbook to workbook (get name of active workbook)

        set noOfTabs to count of worksheets of active workbook --get numer of tabs in target spreadsheet

        repeat with x from 1 to noOfTabs --get all tab names
            set tabnames to the name of every sheet
        end repeat

        set selectedTabName to (choose from list tabnames) as string --get user to choose which tab to copy

        set destWorkbook to make new workbook --create new workbook
        set destWorkbook to workbook (get name of active workbook)
        tell destWorkbook --get count of tabs
            set lastsheet to sheet (count of sheets)
        end tell
        tell sourceWorkbook
            set sourcesheet to sheet selectedTabName
            copy worksheet sourcesheet after lastsheet of workbook destWorkbook --copy sourcesheet to new workbook
        end tell

        tell destWorkbook

            --get save path and add filename
            set selectedPath to paragraphs of (do shell script "/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog" & " fileselect --title 'Select Folder to save to' --text  --with-directory $HOME/Dropbox/Business/Timesheets/2015/ --select-only-directories") & "/JML Timesheet " & selectedTabName as string

            set destWorkbookName to (POSIX file selectedPath) as string 

            save workbook as destWorkbook filename destWorkbookName file format workbook normal file format overwrite yes --save new workbook 

        end tell
    end tell
    set choice to 2
end repeat
```

What am i doing wrong?  I need to sort this bit out before I can move on to wrapping up and putting the workbook into an email as an attachment.

Thanks in advance

Jez

Comment: I've added an answer below. If it works for you then mark the answer as solving otherwise provide more feedback if it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Jez M-L

The following copy sheet worked in a local sample with Yosemite and Excel 2011 for Mac. You can substitute the hard-coded file names (wkbkSrcName and wkbkTargName) with dialogs or whatever as you see fit:

```
set wkbkPath to (POSIX path of (run script "path to desktop")) as text
set wkbkSrcName to "clasew-ex5-sample1a.xlsx"
set wkbkTargName to "sample-target.xlsx"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    launch
    local fullSrcFile, fullTargFile, srcSheet, lastTargSheet, wkbkSrc, wkbkTarg

    set fullSrcFile to (wkbkPath & wkbkSrcName)
    open fullSrcFile
    set wkbkSrc to workbook wkbkSrcName
    set srcSheet to sheet 1 of wkbkSrc

    set wkbkTarg to make new workbook
    set lastTargSheet to sheet (count of sheets) of wkbkTarg

    copy worksheet srcSheet after lastTargSheet

    tell wkbkTarg
        set fullTargFile to (POSIX file wkbkPath & wkbkTargName) as text
        save workbook as filename fullTargFile overwrite yes
    end tell

end tell
```

This may be useful to fit back into your logic.

Comment: Belatedly, you could forego `lastTargSheet` by targeting `sheet -1`: eg`copy worksheet srcSheet after sheet -1`